# Class not getting called in WSO2 API in MicroIntegrator

Tags: java, api, class, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to call class from a WSO2 API. I have copied the JAR file of class mediator project to `<MI_HOME>/lib`. However, I am still getting this error:

> Error loading class : com.test.mediator.ChangeValue - Class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.mediator.ChangeValue cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v182

For a little better understanding calling class in sequence is as follows:

```
 <class name="com.test.mediator.ChangeValue"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="After CLASS" value="in Seq"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:NameN" name="NameClass"/>
</log>
```

For class, the class definition is as follows:

```
package com.test.mediator;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class ChangeValue extends AbstractMediator {

public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
    // TODO Implement your mediation logic here 
    changeVal(context);
    return true;
}

public void changeVal(MessageContext context) {
    String Namem = (String) context.getProperty("NAMEE");
    String Namen = "Hary";
    context.setProperty("NameN", Namen);
  }
}
```

Why is this error showing up?

Comment: Is this a jar or bundle? If a bundle, use MI/dropins folder

Comment: Also, check whether you already have the same Jar in `MI/dropins` or `MI/lib` directory. If so delete the Jar from both places and copy it to `MI/lib`.

Comment: @ycr Yes everything is as mentioned in your comment.. But its still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

This error indicated the MI is unable to load the custom class during the run time. Follow the below steps and try it out.

1. Stop the server if already running.
2. Remove the class mediator from MI/dropins and MI/lib folders.
3. In the custom mediator project check the pom.xml file to check the packaging type. (There should be a tag `<packaging>bundle/jar</packaging>`).
4. If pom contains `<packaging>bundle</packaging>`, copy the jar to `MI/dropins` directly. If pom does not contains  tag or contains packaging with value jar as `<packaging>jar</packaging>` copy the mediator jar to `MI/lib` folder.
5. Restart the server and try out.